# Como utilizar o SUM para somar os valores entre uma determinada data

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso da quantidade total vendida entre duas datas, estou tendo dificuldade com o SUM para essa soma em especifico meu conhecimento em SQL é limitadíssimo.

```
SELECT Qtde_Vendida, `Data`
FROM vendas, tempo
WHERE `Data` BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
SELECT SUM (Qtde_vendida) FROM vendas
```

Como utilizar o Select Sum para que ele some a quanditade de vendas dentro de um determinado período ?

Comment: Publique a estrutura das tabelas , Veja a síntaxe do JOIN e do GROUP BY ... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html ... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

Sua lógica estava correta. A única questão é que o `sum` vem direto no `select`, portanto o `select` acima não era muito necessário; exceto se você for realizar um `inner join`. Nesse caso, será diferente. O script me informa se ele relaciona com outra tabela que então realizo um script diferente para questão

```sql
create table dat (
    data datetime,
    qtde_vendida int,
    )


select sum(dat)

insert dat values (getdate(), 1000)
insert dat values (getdate(), 1500)
insert dat values (getdate(), 1700)

select * from dat

update dat set data = '2020-06-09 11:35:24.580' where qtde_vendida = 1700
update dat set data = '2021-06-09 11:35:24.580' where qtde_vendida = 1000



select sum(qtde_vendida) as soma from dat where data between '2020-06-09 11:35:24.580' and '2022-06-09 11:35:24.580'
```